# Error loading page (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)(..) in firefox

Tags: firefox, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, windows-7

While executing script I got above kind of error my script stopping at adding certification exception point(please refer attached image). Even though I added manually certification exception still my script is stopping at that point and at console error.

Error loading page (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)(..) in firefox.

```js
023 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error loading page (WARNING: The server
did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.26 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '31c43c8', time: '2016-08-02 21:57:56
-0700'
System info: host: 'Admin-HP', ip: '10.242.2.2', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, firefoxOpti
ons={args=[], prefs={}}, appBuildId=20161031133903, version=, platform=XP, proxy
={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, browserVersion=47
.0.2, platformVersion=6.1, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, brow
serName=Firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName
=Windows_NT, device=desktop}]
Session ID: b35aff8f-6441-4ca7-8de6-60ab196a4b56
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.
java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHa
ndler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.ja
va:683)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:3
31)
```

Platform - windows 7
language - java
tool - selenium webdriver 3.0.1
Firefox version - 47.0.2

please help me out to resolve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to start Firefox browser using Selenium V3

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette",D:\\JW\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.8.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe);
```

And below code is to handle SSL certificate exceptions in Firefox

```
firefoxProfile profile=new firefoxProfile();
Profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
firefoxDriver driver=new firefoxDriver(profile);
```

You need to use GeckoDriver from Selenium V3 to run Firefox. I tried with Selenium v3 and Firefox v47
SO this works

```
    FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","PATH to geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: I am getting error if I used your solution my browser also not opening.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;

Comment: Only I want is to add ssl certification exception in script so that my script will not stop

Comment: Updated my answer, Pl. try

Comment: I can able to login now but browser is not closing. Eventhough I used driver.close cammand.

Comment: driver.close() will close the current browser window
driver.quit() will close the current driver session.

You may be having more than one window, so try with quit()

Comment: Now I am facing new problem with same script error is as : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055;